# NAudio looping an audio file

Tags: naudio

I already have the code of the mp3/wma audio playing/stopping and browsing. I just need to know how can I loop the song?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a blog post I wrote on how to [loop audio using NAudio](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/10/looped-playback-in-net-with-naudio.html).

Answer (score 4):

Use an array for yours files name, then you can free to loop the song.

Answer (score 1):

Just handle PlaybackStopped Event, then you can play again the audio.