# Looping mp3 using Naudio

Tags: c#, loops, mp3, naudio

I play mp3 using NAudio but I don't know how to loop the music during opening program?

```
IWavePlayer waveOutDevice = new WaveOut();
AudioFileReader musicBackground = new AudioFileReader(@"....mp3");
waveOutDevice.Init(musicBackground);
waveOutDevice.Play();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NAudio looping an audio file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792456/naudio-looping-an-audio-file)

Comment: Already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792456/naudio-looping-an-audio-file) :)